# Update location cast_coordinate throws argument error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a `locations` table that keep the user `latitude` and `longitude`. I am using `Postgres/Postgis 13` that come with extension to generate coordinate. Below is my model:

```
  schema "locations" do
    field :latitude, :float
    field :longitude, :float
    field :context, :string
    field :publish, :boolean
    field :coordinates, Geo.PostGIS.Geometry
    belongs_to(:user, User)

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(location, attrs) do
    location
    |> cast(attrs, [:user_id, :context, :longitude, :latitude, :publish])
    |> validate_required([:user_id, :context, :longitude, :latitude])
    |> cast_coordinates()
  end

  @spec cast_coordinates(Ecto.Changeset.t()) :: Ecto.Changeset.t()
  def cast_coordinates(changeset) do
    IO.inspect(changeset)
    lat = get_change(changeset, :latitude)
    lng = get_change(changeset, :longitude)
    geo = %Geo.Point{coordinates: {lng, lat}, srid: 4326}
    changeset |> put_change(:coordinates, geo)
  end
```

when I `create_location`:

```
  def create_location(attrs \\ %{}) do
    IO.inspect(attrs)
    %Location{}
    |> Location.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.insert()
  end
```

Everything works successfully. The `changeset` in `cast_coordinates` is:

```
cast coordinate
#Ecto.Changeset<
  action: nil,
  changes: %{
    context: "sss shop",
    latitude: 38.115556,
    longitude: 13.361389,
    profile_id: 5,
    publish: true,
    user_id: 2
  },
  errors: [],
  data: #OkBackend.Gis.ProfileLocation<>,
  valid?: true
>
```

But when I `update_location`:

```
  def update_location(%Location{} = location, attrs) do
    location
    |> Location.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.update()
  end
```

Somehow my `cast_coordinate` throw `argument error`, because `changeset` is:

```
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{}, errors: [],


 data: #OkBackend.Gis.ProfileLocation<>, valid?: true>
```

As you can see, there is nothing inside the `changes`.

Why is that? And how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because in your `cast_coordinates` function, you are using `get_change(changeset, :longitude)`.

This will get a `change` to the `longitude` field, but if you're not changing the field then it will return `nil`.

You instead should use `get_field(changeset, :longitude)` to get the changed longitude or the existing longitude if it hasn't changed, like this:

```
  @spec cast_coordinates(Ecto.Changeset.t()) :: Ecto.Changeset.t()
  def cast_coordinates(changeset) do
    lat = get_field(changeset, :latitude)
    lng = get_field(changeset, :longitude)
    geo = %Geo.Point{coordinates: {lng, lat}, srid: 4326}
    changeset |> put_change(:coordinates, geo)
  end
```